# Query with conditions based on cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to write a VBA code that Queries some values.

My SQL query has two conditions in the WHERE statement.

- The value in column B is within the query, so no issue about it.
- The value in column A is a code which starts with numbers, but contains Letters and should be seen as a string as such to work '6F3S'; specifically: database.columnA='6F3S'.

My issue comes from the fact that I want to outsource the element 6F3S in cell D1 in sheet "Input_sheet", so that the user can change it with other codes if necessary.

This is my code so far:

```vb
Sub Query1()
    Dim ValueCellD1 As String
    ValueCellD1 = Worksheets("Input_Sheet").Range("D1").Value
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "FFFF;DSN=XXXXXXXXXXXX;", Destination:=Range("$A$7")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT database.columnA, database.columnB, database.columnC" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "FROM IMPALA.database database" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (database.columnA=ValueCellD1) AND (database.columnB='London')")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive a

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

When I try to debug it appears being here:

```vb
.CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT database.columnA, database.columnB, database.columnC" _
            & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "FROM IMPALA.database database" _
            & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
            "WHERE (database.columnA=ValueCellD1) AND (database.columnB='London')")
```

Note: I am currently using Excel 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get `ValueCellD1` out of the string so it is recognized as variable.

```vb
.CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT database.columnA, database.columnB, database.columnC" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "FROM IMPALA.database database" _
        & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (database.columnA='" & ValueCellD1 & "') AND (database.columnB='London')")
```

Actually I have no idea why you insert `& Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) &` in your string. The following should work too:

```vb
.CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT database.columnA, database.columnB, database.columnC " _
        "FROM IMPALA.database database " _
        "WHERE (database.columnA='" & ValueCellD1 & "') AND (database.columnB='London')")
```

Note that if you read a cell value into your variable

```vb
ValueCellD1 = Worksheets("Input_Sheet").Range("D1").Value
```

and push this into your SQL command without verifying the cell value, then anyone who can edit the cell value in D1 can easily attack your database and run any SQL command he likes (eg delete it). **Never trust user input. Always validate it**.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe that the Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) comes from the fact that I started the VBA as a recorded macro.